# Ways to optimise this code

Tags: c++, string, caching, optimization, increment

I am exploring ways to optimise the code that follows. 
The code loops over a string. For the ith
character in the string,
the code increments one entry in a 2D array at the
ith column. The exact entry at the ith column
that is incremented depends on the value of the ith character in the string;
there is one row for each letter in the strings alphabet.
By looping over multiple strings and incrementing the same 2d array (`count`),
the number of occurrences of each character is calculated for the strings.

The code is as follows:

```
string read = getReadFromData();
vector< vector<int> > count(4,vector<int>(read.size(),0));
for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++) {
  switch(read[i]) {                                           
    case 'A': count[0][i]++; break;
    case 'T': count[1][i]++; break;
    case 'C': count[2][i]++; break;
    case 'G': count[3][i]++; break;
}
```

My attempt at optimisation has been to make use of a 1d array, instead
of a 2d array; aiming to avoid cache misses if the string data itself
is not contiguous in memory. 
Unfortunately, it has not reduced the computation time; they are roughly equivalent.

```
string read = getReadFromData();
int width = read.size()
vector<int> count(4*width,0);
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  switch(read[i]) {                                           
    case 'A': count[            i]++; break;
    case 'T': count[    width + i]++; break;
    case 'C': count[2 * width + i]++; break;
    case 'G': count[3 * width + i]++; break;
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to optimise this problem?
Switching rows and columns? Or changing the interval of the increments?
Thanks for any advice.

**Update: An optimisation**
So, I believe the main issues were:

1) Unpredictability of the input; the memory location accessed in either the
2D or 1D versions depend on the input character.
2) In the 1D example, the distance between corresponding positions were far apart. Also, in 2D, but i'm optimising 1D example.

In the 1D example above, the potential positions of `i+1` are very far apart; `i+1`, `i+1 + width`, `i+1 + 2*width`, `i+1 + 3*width`. I think the unpredictability of access, coupled with the large distance to `i+1`, leads to excessive cache misses - I'll cachegrind at some point.
The aim of the optimisation is to reduce the distance to the `i+1`th access.
To do this I interleave the A,T,G,C counts, such that the `i+1`th element
is at  most 7 entries away; a much smaller distance.

```
string read = getReadFromData();
int width = read.size()
vector<int> count(4*width,0);
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  switch(read[i]) {                                           
    case 'A': count[i*4    ]++; break;
    case 'T': count[i*4 + 1]++; break;
    case 'C': count[i*4 + 2]++; break;
    case 'G': count[i*4 + 3]++; break;
}
```

I'm getting a > 5x speedup now, which is tasty.

Comment: Feedback requests for working code will get better results from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use SSE instructions. Intrinsics are the way to go.

Comment: Are you excluding `getReadFromData()` from your timing comparisons?

Comment: 1)Profile & measure; determine *where* the bottleneck is. 2) Turn on the compiler's optimization switches and profile again.  3) Review the assembly language generated by the compiler to see if you can improve it.

Comment: Your optimizations have no effect.  The position in the array is either calculated by the compiler (first version posted) or by you (in the second example).   In order to optimize, you will need a different data structure.

Comment: Yes, try switching rows and columns, and do use a single 1d vector. That is, `case 'T': count[4*i+1]++; break;`
`

Comment: Alternatively, don't switch rows and columns, but make 4 separate passes like this: `for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++) if (read[i]=='A')count[i]++; for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++) if (read[i]=='B')count[width+i]++;` etc

Comment: @n.m. implementing this now...

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to precalculate the arrays as pointers:
*Note: untested code follows*

```
vector< vector<int> > count(4,vector<int>(read.size(),0));
std::vector<int> * const p_a_counts = &count[0];
std::vector<int> * const p_t_counts = &count[1];
std::vector<int> * const p_c_counts = &count[2];
std::vector<int> * const p_g_counts = &count[3];

for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++) {
  switch(read[i]) {                                           
    case 'A': p_a_counts->[i]++; break;
    case 'T': p_t_counts->[i]++; break;
    case 'C': p_c_counts->[i]++; break;
    case 'G': p_g_counts->[i]++; break;
}
```

The idea is to reduce the calculation for the various arrays.

*Note:  You code doesn't look correct.  If the 2nd letter read is 'T', then the second location is incremented, not the first.  Although you could be counting the number of times that 'T' is in the 2nd position.*

**Edit 1:  A different perspective**
Processors prefer to access the same data region, in other words make use of their data cache.

So, change the perspective to a data point of view:

```
string read = getReadFromData();
vector< vector<int> > count(4,vector<int>(read.size(),0));

for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++)
{
  if (read[i] == 'A')
  {                                           
    count[0][i]++;
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++)
{
  if (read[i] == 'T')
  {                                           
    count[1][i]++;
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++)
{
  if (read[i] == 'C')
  {                                           
    count[2][i]++;
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++)
{
  if (read[i] == 'G')
  {                                           
    count[3][i]++;
  }
}
```

The above should keep the `count` array inside the data cache for the different purposes.

Comment: In my opinion, your performance bottleneck is not with the `switch` statement, but maybe elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I am counting the number of times that 'T' is in the 2nd position; it's correct.

Comment: I think i'll heed you're advice and use perf to check out the assembly. What do you make of the interleaving I mentioned? `i*0`, `i*1`,... for the separate letters. I think this is a more predicable pattern for the prefetcher; In my failed optimisation, the entry to increment of the next character could be  anywhere between `1-3*read.size() + 1` distance away. If I interleave, the next position will be between `1-4 int`s away.

Comment: Try my edited version #1.  You want to have all your data accesses as close to the cache line as possible.  Also search the internet for "Data driven optimization".

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Matthews has suggested in his comment to use a different data structure, often standard library given data structures are slower than you might like. Try using just a regular array

```
int *count = new int [4 * width];
```

Comment: A better idea would be to create 4 separate arrays and make 4 passes through the data read in.  This allows the processor to keep only 2 arrays in the data cache and have less data cache misses.

Comment: There is no reason in the world why a modern compiler would generate slower code for std::vector than for plain array.